# Search number and delete the records

Tags: excel, vba

The below coding in just searching string and deleting the records but when we search number, it is not deleting the records. Please advise as to what went wrong.

The below coding is not working for number (integer)and only works for string.

```
Dim myFileNameDir As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim iRow1 As Long
Dim str As String


myFileNameDir = "C:\Users\GShaikh\Desktop\Book16.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFileNameDir, UpdateLinks:=0
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Students")

str = ListView1.SelectedItem.SubItems(1)

MsgBox str


With ws1
       .AutoFilterMode = False
      iRow1 = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

     With .Range("B1:D" & iRow1)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & str & "*"
           .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
      End With

     .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: This code looks for the text that is stored in str within the cells content. If you want to look for a specific number you can change the content of str to include those numbers. You can also take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx

Comment: This is likely the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520060/autofilter-not-seeing-numerical-data-in-filtered-view-multiple-values/30533149#30533149.  If so, this is a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

You can try as follow:

```
Dim rowCount, row As Integer
Dim myFileNameDir, str As String

myFileNameDir = "C:\Users\GShaikh\Desktop\Book16.xlsx"

Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFileNameDir, UpdateLinks:=0

str = ListView1.SelectedItem.SubItems(1)

'Set start row for checking
row = 1

With Sheets("Students")

    'Getting total row count
    rowCount = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    'Loop until row less than or equal with row count
    Do While row <= rowCount

        'If string is found in B or C or D, delete row and decrease rowCount
        If .Range("B" & row) = str Or .Range("C" & row) = str Or .Range("D" & row) = str Then

            .Rows(row).EntireRow.Delete

            rowCount = rowCount - 1

        'Else move to next row
        Else

            row = row + 1

        End If

    Loop

End With
```

Comment: This will delete the first row below the header regardless if it was returned by the filter.  It will also only delete 1 row whereas OP is deleting from all returned results.  And finally, the use of an unqualified `Rows` is likely to cause problems since OP is using `ws1` and not necessarily making it the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: It's getting further from the ideal.  OP is using `*` with the `AutoFilter` so it is using wildcards, yours is just equality.  OP has good code to delete the results.  Their problem is likely trying to use `contains` or wildcard searching on numbers.  It doesn't work.